# Learning Vector Quantization (LVQ) Unbalance Input Size

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, training-data, mfcc

I'm new learning LVQ, and i want to implement it with my [mfcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) (Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients) result.
So far as i learn, 
every example that i studied have uniform training and input data size array like:

> x1[2][4]  = {{0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1},[{1,1,0,1}}
>
> x2[2][4]  = {{0,1,1,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1}}
>
> x3[2][4]  = {{1,0,1,0},{1,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1}}

But my mfcc results data size are unbalance like :

> x1[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)[4]  = {{0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1}}
>
> x2[2][4]  = {{0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1}}
>
> x2[4][4]  = {{0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,1},{1,0,1,0}}

so how can i deal with this unbalanced data size for LVQ training and input?

Comment: What is mfcc?. Try to explain your problem better. For example you can give example data.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur mfcc is Mel-frequency cepstral coefficient, usually used for audio recognition. i already edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most basic thing to try in this problem is to fill missing values by 0 components. Since your Mel-frequency cepstral coefficient is basically fourier transform, then second fourier transform. This should have no effect.

Try to find maximum size of your input vector. Then fill other smaller input vectors missing dimensions with 0. Like below.

> x1[1][4]  = {{0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1},,{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}}
>
> x2[2][4]  = {{0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}}
>
> x2[4][4]  = {{0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,1},{1,0,1,0}}

Comment: thank you for your answer, ill try it and see if its working, but what if i have another input that have more size than the maximum size, like :               >x4[6][4] = {{1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,1},{1,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,1},{1,0,0,0},{1,0,1,1}}